# Parse xml and combine child attribute

Tags: r, xml, xpath

I am working with a xml file with the following structure below which I am trying to display each unique  into a dataframe. I know I can retrieve each child attribute (e.g., ) using the xpathApply function but notice that the //channel//item//category[@domain='tag'] contains different counts. How would I be able to put these categories all in one cell separated by a comma? Would you loop over each child attribute ?

Here's a test.xml

```
test.xml <- "<channel>
        <item>
        <title>Article Name 1</title>
        <creator>User1</creator>
        <post_id>1000</post_id>
        <category domain='tag' nicename='red'>Red</category>
        <category domain='store' nicename='clothes'>Clothes</category>
        </item>     
        <item>
        <title>Article Name 2</title>
        <creator>User3</creator>
        <post_id>232</post_id>
        <category domain='tag' nicename='blue'>Blue</category>
        <category domain='tag' nicename='green'>Green</category>
     <category domain='tag' nicename='yellow'>Yellow</category>
        <category domain='store' nicename='clothes'>Other</category>
        </item> 
        <item>
        <title>Article Name 3</title>
        <creator>User4</creator>
        <post_id>4532</post_id>
        <category domain='tag' nicename='red'>Red</category>
        <category domain='tag' nicename='blue'>Blue</category>
        <category domain='store' nicename='clothes'>Food</category>
        </item>         
    </channel>"

xml <- xmlParse(test.xml)
```

The end goal should look like this:

| title | creator | tag | store |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Article 1 | User 1 | Red | Clothes |
| Article 2 | User 3 | Blue, Green | Other |
| Article 3 | User 4 | Red, Blue | Food |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the xml2 package. It is straight forward, read the "item" parent nodes, and parse out the title and creator.  Then using `lapply` process each parent node to parse and merge the multiple child nodes together.  Finally merger everything together.

```
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
#read page and parent nodes
page <- read_xml(test.xml)
items <- page %>% xml_find_all("item")

#get title and creator (assuming 1 per parent)
title <- items %>% xml_find_first("title") %>% xml_text()
creator <- items %>% xml_find_first("creator") %>% xml_text()

#find the multip;e tag and store nodes per parent
#collapse the multiples into 1 value
dfs <- lapply(items, function(node){
   tag <- node %>% xml_find_all(xpath='.//category[@domain="tag"]') %>% xml_text()
  tag <- paste(tag, collapse = ", ")
  
 store <- node %>% xml_find_all(xpath='.//category[@domain="store"]') %>% xml_text()
 store <- paste(store, collapse = ", ")
 
 data.frame(tag, store)
})

#combine everything into 1 data frame
finalanswer <- data.frame(title, creator, bind_rows(dfs))
```